# Segmentation Fault when assigning value to a pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault

When I run the following parallel code I get a segmentation fault at the assignment at row 18 (between the two prints). I don't really understand what is causing.

This is a minimal working example which describes the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>


struct Worker{

    std::vector<int>* v;
    
    void f(){
            
        std::vector<int> a(20);
        std::iota(a.begin(), a.end(), 1);

        auto b = new std::vector<int>(a);
        std::cout << "Test 1" << std::endl;
        v = b;
        std::cout << "Test 2" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int nw = 1;
 
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(nw);
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Worker>> W;

    for(int i = 0; i < nw; i++){
        W.push_back(std::make_unique<Worker>());
        threads[i] = std::thread([&]() { W[i]->f(); } );

        // Pinning threads to cores
        cpu_set_t cpuset;
        CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
        CPU_SET(i, &cpuset);
        pthread_setaffinity_np(threads[i].native_handle(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nw; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
        std::cout << (*(W[i]->v))[0] << std::endl;
    }
    
}
```

It seems that compiling it with -fsanitize=address the code works fine but I get worst performances. How can I make it work?

Comment: `cpu_set_t cpuset;` -- This is a local variable that disappears or gets recycled every time the loop iterates, yet you are using the address of this variable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I dont think that matter because he set the nw to 1, so the loop only get exec once

Comment: So what happens when that loop terminates?  That local variable now no longer exists.

Comment: @LuânNguyễn I tried push_back(move) but I get the same segmentation fault

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie even removing that block of code I get the segmentation fault at the same line. Anyway, I think those lines do their work and actually pin the threads to the cores. I did some experiments and I got a good increase on speedup using those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the vector synchronization problem mentioned by Sam, there is another problem.

This line:

```
threads[i] = std::thread([&]() { W[i]->f(); } );
```

captures `i` by reference. There is a good chance that `i` goes out of scope (and is destroyed) before the thread starts running. The statement `W[i]->f();` is likely to read an invalid value of `i` which is negative or too large. Note that before `i` goes out of scope, the last value written to it is `nw`, so if even if the memory that previously contained `i` is still accessible, it's likely to have the value `nw` which is too large.

You could fix *this* problem by capturing `i` by value:

```
threads[i] = std::thread([&W, i]() { W[i]->f(); } );
//                        ^^^^^
// captures W by reference, and i by value
```

Comment: Tested this. Can confirm

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` is not thread-safe. None of the containers in the C++ library are thread safe.

```
threads[i] = std::thread([&]() { W[i]->f(); } );
```

The new execution thread captures the vector by reference and accesses it.

```
W.push_back(std::make_unique<Worker>());
```

The original execution thread continuously modifies the vector here, without synchronizing access to the `W` vector with any of the new execution threads. Any `push_back` may invalidate the existing contents of the vector in order to reallocate it, and if a different execution thread attempts to get `W[i]` at the same time, while it's being reallocated, hillarity ensues.

This is undefined behavior.

You must either synchronize access to the vector using a mutex, or make sure that the vector will never be reallocated, using any number of known techniques. A sufficiently-large `reserve()`, in advance, should do the trick.

Additionally, it's been pointed out that `i` is also captured by reference, so by the time each new execution thread starts, its value could be anything.

Comment: This is *a* problem, but I don't think it's *the* problem. I think *the* problem is that by the time any of the threads start up, `i` has the value of `nw`

Comment: Yup, that's also true, noted.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, the capture is the problem.

I've added the `i` parameter to the `f()` call:

```
    void f(int i){
            
        std::vector<int> a(20);
        std::iota(a.begin(), a.end(), 1);

        auto b = new std::vector<int>(a);
        std::cout << "Test 1 " << i << std::endl;
        v = b;
        std::cout << "Test 2 " << v->size() << std::endl;
    }
```

and the output: `Test 1 1`

The call to `f` works however but it is called without a valid `Worker` instance and when you assign to `v` it is surely at a wrong memory.